# Explanations on Hmac User Authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I'm trying to implement the authentication system explains in this article [Hmac User Authentication](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HmacUserAuthentication).

I don't understand the following part :

> Server sends back: let MESSAGE = (USERNAME,REALM,SALT,SESSIONID,ENCRYPTED_SESSION_KEY) in auth:(MESSAGE,HMAC(SHA1,PASSHASH,MESSAGE)).

I don't know how to generate the SESSIONID and the ENCRYPTED_SESSION_KEY. And what is the "auth" ?

Answer (score 0):

As there was no answer to my question, I give the solution I am using.

In my case, I replaced SESSION_ID by a timestamp. I generated the ENCRYPTED_SESSION_KEY with HMAC(SHA1, PASSHASH, SESSION_ID). And finally "auth" is a json response.

Hope, it helps someone hitting this page.